# Solve the following differential equation with the initial constraint

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$dW/dt = 1/25 * (W-300) $$

Initial constraint W(0) = 1400

The solution I obtained is $W(t) = e^{0.04t}+1400$

$\int{\frac{dW}{(W-300)}} = \int{\frac{1}{25} dt  }$

$ e^{ln(W-300)} = e^{\frac{1}{25}t}+C$
$W-300 = e^{\frac{1}{25}t}+C$
$W(t) = e^{\frac{1}{25}t}+C+300$
Initial Constraint: $1400=1+300+C$
$C=1100$
$W(t) = e^{0.04t}+1400$

Apparently it is supposed to be $1100e^{0.04t}+300$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is small $w$ here?

Comment: @Wwk same thing as capital W except I do not know how to do it in the mathJAX

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line

$$\int\frac{dW}{(W-300)} = \int\frac{1}{25}\,dt$$

you should get

$$\ln|W-300| = \frac{t}{25}+C$$

then

$$e^{\ln|W-300|} = e^{t/25+C}$$

Note that $C$ is in the exponent. In other words, you put the arbitrary constant in the wrong place. You also left out an absolute value, though that is minor here since you will later find that one of the possible signs for $W-300$ is extraneous. Continue from there.